# how to connect bigquery to Python with collab?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace, integer

How can I convert a string to an integer in sql?

Comment: [Cast, convert functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` function to convert string to integer.

```sql
SELECT CAST('123' AS INT)
```

Alternatively, you can use `CONVERT` function.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '123')
```